# Unreal Engine cannot generate .uexp file

Tags: file, simulator, carla

I created a map level using Unreal Engine. When I save the project I am able to see the `map.umap` and `map_BuildData.uasset`.

I need `map.uexp` file in order to load it into another application. How can I generate it?

I understood that I need to follow the following steps:

1. Project Setting -> Packing-> Build Configuration-> Development.
2. File->Package Project -> Linux.

These steps do not help me at all to produce that file?
How can I generate it?